# Python equal operator for finite precision

Tags: python

I need to use Python operator == to evaluate whether the components of two matrices are equal to each other to a specific precision (say only the first three digits is important to me). Is there a way to pass the precision to this operator?

Comment: Have you looked at [numpy](http://www.numpy.org)? Specifically, [.isClose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html)?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: I marked as duplicate because there are good answers for that line of thought. Best of luck!

Comment: If you are on Python 3.5+, you can also use [math.isclose](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/math.html). Since you mention matrices than `numpy` is probably your best bet.